# .gitignore whitelist * not working correctly

Tags: git

I have attempted to create a whitelist in my .gitignore file as such:

```
#Ignore everything
*
#Don't ignore directories, so we can recurse into them
!*/
#Don't ignore files
!*/docs
#!cmd_mux.vhd
!.gitignore
!*.vhd
!*.v
!*.fdo
!*.xise
```

However, Git is still ignoring cmd_mux.vhd. If I uncomment the line that directly specifies cmd_mux.vhd, it works fine.

What's going on here?

Comment: Do you have any other gitignore files? they might be overriding the one you have shown

Comment: Other places to check: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Comment: git version 1.8.3.2 works fine. You have something else you are not telling.

Comment: My .git/info/exclude file is empty and I do not have a global  gitignore file. I'm using git version 1.7.0.4

Comment: @user1526283: It's also fine in 1.7.9.5. Do you have anything in `git config --global core.excludesfile`?

Answer (score 6):

You could try the check-ignore command to debug the ignore process:

```
$ git check-ignore cmd_mux.vhd -v
.gitignore:7:!cmd_mux.vhd
```

It should print out the pattern (whith the enclosing file) that affects the ignore status of your file.